# is it possible to clone content that includes javascript and maintain state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My end goal is to copy an iframe and move it to a popup window. The iframe contains a lot of javascript code, which is where my problem comes in.

I'm able to clone the contents and add it to the popup.

```
    editWindow = window.open('');
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(editWindow.document).contents().find('head').parent().replaceWith($('#box').contents().find("html").clone(true));
```

**Javascript**

```
    var head_inner = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].cloneNode(true);
    var body_inner = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].cloneNode(true);
    var old_head = editWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var old_body = editWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    old_head.parentNode.replaceChild(head_inner, old_head);
    old_body.parentNode.replaceChild(body_inner, old_body);
```

Both of those approaches add the contents to the popup window, but the javascript that is there isn't executable. Trying to call a function in the new window results in undefined errors.

The only way I can get the javascript executable is to use

```
    editWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");
    editWindow.document.write('<html>');
    .....
    editWindow.document.close();
```

I can then run the code that's added to the new window, however none of the javascript variables from the iframe retain their values.

Is what I'm attempting to do possible? I can't find anything that references cloning an entire page along with javascript code. Google is doing something similar with their gmail chat, where you can popout an already started conversation into it's own window and then merge it back in.

Thanks for any insight into this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you own the HTML and JavaScript, there is a way to save state on the object itself... t

```
<div id="testel" data-state="10">This is it</div>

<script>

  var el = document.getElementById("testel");

  // Change state
  el.setAttribute("data-state", "20");

  // Clone the node        
  var el2 = el.cloneNode(true);

  // Add to the document, see the state follows.
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(el2);

  // This could also be serialized and sent to another window or frame.
</script>
```

For more information about `data-*` attributes, see: [The HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

**EDIT**

If you need to pass data back and forth, there are two ways:

- [Post Message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)
- [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage2)

`Post Message` lets you send a message to all of the other windows [from that domain] and the windows can pick and choose the messages they respond to.

LocalStorage needs to be polled, but information can be passed around as well.  There are some wrappers to make it easier.

Comment: Much more beautiful than the solution I was about to post. Thanks for sharing - learn something new every day.

Comment: @code4coffee - Glad you liked it.  I updated my answer with a link to more information -- the site I learned about all this stuff.

Comment: that's pretty slick, however if I have something like var myVariable; and then I later manipulate myVariable, how would I clone that javascript? I'm either able to clone everything and then the javascript is no longer executable in the new window, or I can copy it all but I then lose state on any variables that were manipulated

Comment: @Matt -- I added a couple of links that might provide some fodder for thought.  You'll have to decide which of those two will work for you.

Comment: @Jeremy thank you for the additional info. While not directly answering my question you've given me some ideas on workarounds. Thanks for the help!